# How to prevent copy to clipboard in TextInput react-native on Android?

Tags: android, react-native, clipboard

I want to prevent user to copy content in TextInput but it works only on iOS but not for Android. How can I do this on Android?

[Update]: As the [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17335) @patel-dhara has given below, I already read commit about **contextMenuHidden** property and found that only handle *onLongClick* event on Android. So, still can `copy to clipboard` on TextInput by double-tap to it.

**Here is my code:**

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.input}
  placeholder="Password"
  placeholderTextColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)"
  underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
  secureTextEntry={isHidePass}
  returnKeyType="go"
  autoCapitalize="none"
  onChangeText={this.handleTextChange}
  onSubmitEditing={this.handleLogin}
  ref={this.passwordRef}
  contextMenuHidden
  onBlur={() => Clipboard.setString('')}
  onFocus={() => Clipboard.setString('')}
  onSelectionChange={() => Clipboard.setString('')}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use **contextMenuHidden** property of TextInput. It will work on both Platform Android and iOS.

```
<TextInput contextMenuHidden={true} />
```

but, It may be supported after react-native version 0.55. for more info [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/17335).
commit link for that: [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/2dd2529b3ab3ace39136a6e24c09f80ae421a17e)

Comment: yes, I used `contextMenuHidden` property in my code as I describe in the question, but it doesn't work on Android. I developed my app in react-native version 0.57.4.

Comment: on Android, although I add **contextMenuHidden** property to TextInput, I still can copy content in this TextInput by double-tap to it.

Comment: thanks for your reference link. I read the commit about **contextMenuHidden** property and found that only works for long press on Android and not for double-tap. So still can copy to clipboard by double-tap to TextInput field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextInput caretHidden={true} selectTextOnFocus={false} />
```

Comment: I try this too, but not work on Android. I still can copy content in TextInput just by double-tap to it.

Comment: same here, able to copy in android.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
  <TextInput ... />
</View>
```

Checkout pointer events for view:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#pointerevents

Another Option:
Try clearing the clipboard

```
<TextInput onFocus={() => Clipboard.setString('')} onSelectionChange={() => Clipboard.setString('')}/>
```

Comment: If using this, users can't even select to TextInput. This is bad practice.

Comment: yes it is, the best practise is either cartHidden={true} or contextMenuHidden={true}
or you can also try in the same code I provided with `pointerEvents="box-none"`
which RN version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 0.57.4. As I updated my question above, `contextMenuHidden` property work only with *onLongClick* event, so users still can copy to clipboard just by double-tap to it.

Comment: I just edited my answer. please try the second solution. may be this can help you!

Comment: I did this as I described in the question. But it actually not effective!

Answer (score 0):

I you want to avoid pasting below solution works for me. I am clearing keyboard on onTouchEnd event

```
const [text1, setText1] = useState('')
    
const clearClipboard = () =>{
 Clipboard.setString('')
}
    
const onChangeText = (text) =>{
 //For android 12+ clipboard autofill option, dont allow text change more than one char..which means user is typing.
 if(text1.length+1 >= text.length){
  setText1(text)
 }
}
    
<TextInput onChangeText={onChangeText} value={text1} contextMenuHidden={true} onTouchEnd={clearClipboard}></TextInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to solve this problem was to use the onFocus from TextInput to Clear the Clipboard. This way I don't need to prevent the user from pasting because even if he does the clipboard will be empty.

You can do the same with onBlur to prevent the content that was coppied to be pasted.

```
                   <InputCustom
                     onFocus={() => {                          
                        Clipboard.setString('');
                      }}           
                     onBlur={() => {
                        Clipboard.setString('');
                      }}                         
                    />
```